# How to use Microsoft Office 365 online OUTLOOK with Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online

Tags: dynamics-crm-online

I need to use Microsoft Office 365 online OUTLOOK with Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online.

but I am unable to find anything related to this.

I found one link related to this but the option/view suggested in this link seems not appearing actually.

http://www.sysco-software.com/office-365-integration-with-dynamics-crm/

see the Web Mail Client section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to use this and it's working fine.

https://technet.microsoft.com/library/dn946901.aspx